# Weighted colimits,hom-functor,Usage of Yoneda lemma

Tags: category-theory

I have a question about weighted colimits.
Let $D:E\rightarrow Set$ be a diagram,and $\phi:E^{op} \rightarrow Set$ a weight.
$\phi*D \in Set$ is defined by this iso (i.e. a bijection),natural in $X$,

(1) $Set(\phi*D,X)\cong [E^{op},Set](\phi,Set{(D-,X)})$ 
, where $X$ is in Set.

Now,I would like to take for $D$ the homfunctor
$E(d,-)$ where $d$ is in $E$,and apply the Yoneda lemma to get
(2) $\phi(d)\cong \phi *E(d,-)$

But I cannot see how to substitute $E(d,-)$ for $D$ in (1),and how the r.h.s. of (1) reduces by the Yoneda lemma to get the equation (2).
Can you please provide me with a detailed explanation?

Comment: Substitution is just substitution. $E(d, -)$ is a diagram $E \to \mathbf{Set}$, is it not? The tricky bit is applying the Yoneda lemma. I would use the calculus of ends here...

Comment: Can you please do the calculation here or give me a reference?This fact is of importance for me.Also,is $(\phi,Set{(D-,X)})$ in (1) perfectly OK?

Comment: There's no use in me doing the calculation if you don't understand it. Do you know the calculus of ends or not?

Comment: Only what is written in the book CWM.Please,first check syntactically r.h.s. of (1).The calculation you are about to do may of interest for many other people.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the syntax. $\mathbf{Set}(D, X)$ is a functor of type $\mathcal{E}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I use the calculus of ends. First, observe that
$$[\mathcal{E}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}](F, G) \cong \int_{e : \mathcal{E}} \mathbf{Set}(F e, G e)$$
and in particular,
$$[\mathcal{E}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}](\Phi, \mathbf{Set}(D, X)) \cong \int_{e : \mathcal{E}} \mathbf{Set}(\Phi e, \mathbf{Set}(D e, X))$$
but
$$\mathbf{Set}(\Phi e, \mathbf{Set}(D e, X)) \cong \mathbf{Set}(D e, \mathbf{Set}(\Phi e, X))$$
and
$$\int_{e : \mathcal{E}} \mathbf{Set}(D e, \mathbf{Set}(\Phi e, X)) \cong [\mathcal{E}, \mathbf{Set}](D, \mathbf{Set}(\Phi, X))$$
hence:
$$[\mathcal{E}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}](\Phi, \mathbf{Set}(D, X)) \cong [\mathcal{E}, \mathbf{Set}](D, \mathbf{Set}(\Phi, X))$$
Now put $D = \mathcal{E}(d, -)$ and apply the usual Yoneda lemma.

Comment: Whence comes the third iso?Can you please make the last step of applying Yoneda lemma for me to be sure I'm right?

Comment: These are easy. Do you really understand what I'm writing or not?

Comment: My knowledge of ends is not very strong,but I understand that if you "integrate" over elements of $E$ then you get the functor category.But I cannot see now how Yoneda yields $\phi(d)\cong\phi * E(d,-)$;any hint?Your $\Phi$ and $\phi$ from the question are the same?

Comment: Strictly speaking one uses the Yoneda lemma as well as the uniqueness of representing objects for representable functors.

Comment: I'd be quite happy if you take the effort and do the last step to get $\phi(d)$ and explain how uniqueness is used.When objects are more complicated,like functors and natural transformations,I'm never sure what I'm doing.Thank you anyway for your explanation.

Comment: No, I refuse. That step is very basic and you must be able to work out at least that much for yourself if you want to get anywhere with category theory.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17609/discussion-between-user3357120-and-zhen-lin).

Comment: There's all the pieces of the puzzle here, and only simple application of the basic Yoneda iso then fullness of Yoneda embedding left. I wonder if (or wish..) a better syntax would make it visually obvious what the categorical obvious steps should be (at the risk of lacking understanding ?)